# Angular 6 - navigation to child route refreshes whole page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm using Angular 6 and I'm trying to navigate to a child route from the parent route. The navigation is successful, however there is an unwanted page refresh upon rendering the child component. In other words, the navigation works but it also refreshes the page for no apparent reason. Here is my code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "parent/:param1/:param2", component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: ":param3", component: ChildComponent }
        ]
    },
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/index", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "/index" }
];
```

My parent component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "my-parent",
    templateUrl: "./parent.component.html"
})

export class ParentComponent {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
    loading: boolean;
    tutorials: any[];

constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.param1= this.route.snapshot.params.param1;
    this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.params.param2;
    // get data here
    }
}
```

And my child component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "my-child",
    templateUrl: "./child.component.html"
})
export class ChildComponent {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
    param3: string;
    loading: boolean;
    result: any;

    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.param1= this.route.snapshot.params.param1;
        this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.params.param2;
        this.param3 = this.route.snapshot.params.param3;

   }
}
```

Now, the way I try to navigate from the parent component to the child component is the following one:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/parent', param1, param2, param3]">             
    <b>Navigate</b>
</a>
```

As I've said, the navigation is successful, but there is an unwanted page refresh which I want to get rid of and I haven't been able to find a working solution. I don't really know what's causing it. I am new to Angular 6.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

EDIT: added parent component html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="row" *ngIf="route.children.length === 0">
    // content here
</div>
```

Comment: Which module you made the declaration of childComponent?

Comment: I have only one module, both the ParentComponent and ChildComponent are declared in the main app module

Comment: That's not a best practice. All the child components should declared in their parent module. Their routing should specified in parent's routingModule. And in the app-routing.module only parentModule has to specified with loadChildren property. This is how lazy loading works in an effective manner, thereby speed of rendering will increase and page refeshing issues will not occur.

Comment: I'll look into it. Fairly new to this so any and all best practice tips are welcome.

Comment: That will be better

Comment: @AnoopSurendran what do u mean by "All the child components should declared in their parent module"? do u mean the parent module should be something other than the app module? if that's the case, should we create a module for every parent page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a working solution, which while not very elegant, it... works. In my parent component I created a method like this one:

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.param1 = this.route.snapshot.params.param1;
    this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.params.param2;
    // get data
}

navigateToChild(param3: string) {
    this.router.navigate([param3], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

And in the parent template, I did this:

```
<a (click)="navigateToChild(paramFromServer)">
    <b>Navigate</b>
</a>
```

No more refreshes for this one.

Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading / from `[routerLink]= "['/parent'...]"` url. The / is telling the app to find the component route from the root of the application whereas no leading / will try to redirect to the child relative to the current component.

Also make sure you have added a `<router-outlet>` to the parent.component.html as that is where the child component will first try to be added on navigate. If that is not available it might be causing a full refresh to load in the new component from scratch.

Comment: I've added the parent component. The <router-outlet> is there, figured that one out thanks to another question :) .

Comment: Hey, just added an edit that I think may be the cause.

Comment: Let me know if that gives any success

Comment: The navigation works, but the refresh is still there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case 'href' was the problem. Using routerLink solved the problem.

Problematic Approach:

```
<a href='/dashboard/user-details'>User</a>
```

Solution:

```
<a routerLink='/dashboard/user-details'>User</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "parent/:param1/:param2", component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: ":param3", component: ChildComponent }
        ]
    },
  // remove this 2 lines
  // redirect to index thing is not needed
];
```

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. I'll have to keep one for PageNotFoundComponent though.

Comment: Sadly the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define param3 in your ParentComponent. Also you may need to change the strategy of params so your ChildComponent can retrieve the params from its parent.

Please check this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvhgqu

Comment: param3 is a dynamic one, retrieved from the server, hence why it doesn't appear in the parent component.

Comment: But it should be defined publicly so you can access it from the template.